# Cloud firestore transaction lost

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got a problem with concurrent transactions. 
I'm using flutter with cloud firestore plugin version 0.10.0

I got a collection called counters with a document named test. Inside this document i got a field called counter ( number type).
This counter is increased pushing a button from different devices, that's when I understand that a transaction like this makes sense (I attach the piece of code I'm using).

```
DocumentReference counterRef = Firestore.instance.document("counters/test");

                      new FlatButton(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            child: new Text("ADD"),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
                                DocumentSnapshot Ref = await tx.get(counterRef);
                                if(Ref.exists){
                                  print("Updating counter!");
                                  await tx.update(Ref , <String, dynamic>{
                                    'counter': Ref.data['counter'] +1,
                                  }).catchError((e){
                                    print("tx update err:$e");
                                  });
                                }else{
                                  print("No document found in transaction!");
                                }
                              });
                            },
                          ),
```

Using only 2 physical devices, hitting the button at once on both, the counter is only increased 1 time. And i can see on the logs that each device has called the transaction ( i see the Updating counter print on the console )

Where did the result of the second transaction go? Everything seems to have gone well, but the counter has not increased.

Also i see that the new version of the plugin adds a FieldValue.increment, It's not the solution to the problem, because if instead of a counter we use an array for example the same thing happens.

It seems that a transaction has been lost or has read the old value.

Any better idea of how to update a counter from multiple devices?

Comment: https://medium.com/evenbit/on-collision-course-with-cloud-firestore-7af26242bc2d

Comment: Thank you, to make it clear to everyone the issue was related to this firestore limitation.

In Cloud Firestore, you can only update a single document about once per second, which might be too low for some high-traffic applications.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Or this new one
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html

From the link:
In the past, if you wanted to prevent this from happening, you would have to use a transaction. And while transactions are still a fine solution...